# Oracle SQL / OBIEE - Delimit comma separated string for IN clause and handle default values

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I have a direct SQL analysis in OBIEE that uses presentation variables to filter based on Site Name and Unit Name.

The problem is that in OBIEE if the user selects more than one unit (which I want them to be able to do) it outputs the selected units as a comma delimited string `'UNIT 1,UNIT 2,UNIT 3'`.  This is an issue because to then use these values in a SQL filter causes an error as IN expects the strings to be comma separated strings `'UNIT 1', 'UNIT 2', 'UNIT 3'`

I got this working by using `regexp_replace`

```
AND UNIT_LOCATION_NAME in (select regexp_substr('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+', 1, level) as location from dual connect by level <= length(regexp_replace('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+')) + 1)
```

The filtering works fine with this however the default value for `PROMPT_UNIT_NAME` in OBIEE is '(All Column Values)' which means that the analysis returns no results when attempting to query an entire site.

I have attempted to resolve this by handling the default value which is where things have come undone.

```
AND decode('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '(All Column Values)', 1=1, UNIT_LOCATION_NAME in (select regexp_substr('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+', 1, level) AS location FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= length(regexp_replace('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+')) + 1))
```

This throws an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` which is not the case.  There is no missing parenthesis.  Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
    locd.REGION_LOCATION_NAME
    ,locd.SITE_LOCATION_NAME
    ,locd.UNIT_LOCATION_NAME
    ,oi.*
FROM
    cte_oi_v2 oi
    INNER JOIN LOCATION_D locd on locd.LOCATION_ID = oi.UNIT_LOCATION_ID
WHERE
    1=1
    AND SITE_LOCATION_NAME in ('@{PROMPT_SITE_NAME}')
    AND decode('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '(All Column Values)', 1=1, UNIT_LOCATION_NAME in (SELECT regexp_substr('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+', 1, level) AS location FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= length(regexp_replace('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}', '[^,]+')) + 1))
```

Any ideas on what's causing the error or better alternative approaches would be most welcome.

Comment: You are trying to return a string for dynamic SQL. However, OBIEE is likely binding your parameters directly into the SQL statement and executing the SQL statement with binds. Have you tried using boolean logic around your parameter? Something like
**AND ( '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' = '(All Column Values)'  OR ( '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' != '(All Column Values)' AND unit_location_name IN (SELECT regexp_substr('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}','[^,]+',1,level) AS location FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= length(regexp_replace('@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}','[^,]+')) + 1) ) )**

Comment: @JasonSeekWell when the presentation variable equals `(All Column Values)` I don't want the filter to exist at all (so it's only querying site name) hence the attempt to have it return `1=1` which is the equivalent of the filter not existing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This throws an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` which is not the case.

It is the case because `DECODE` does not work like that as you need to return a single value and not an expression to evaluate so you cannot return `1=1` as one of `DECODE`'s arguments and would need to return a single value `1`.

---

Rather than trying use `DECODE` and split the string, you should be able to match the values on sub-strings if you include the surrounding delimiters and use `OR` to alternatively match the default value:

```sql
SELECT locd.REGION_LOCATION_NAME
     , locd.SITE_LOCATION_NAME
     , locd.UNIT_LOCATION_NAME
     , oi.*
FROM   cte_oi_v2 oi
       INNER JOIN LOCATION_D locd
       on locd.LOCATION_ID = oi.UNIT_LOCATION_ID
WHERE  SITE_LOCATION_NAME IN ('@{PROMPT_SITE_NAME}')
AND    (  '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' = '(All Column Values)'
       OR ',' || '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' || ',' LIKE  '%,' || UNIT_LOCATION_NAME || ',%'
       )
```

*Note: you may be able to rewrite `',' || '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' || ','`  as `',@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME},'`.*

Comment: when the presentation variable equals (All Column Values) I don't want the filter to exist at all (so it's only querying site name) hence the attempt to have it return 1=1 which is the equivalent of the filter not existing at al

Comment: @iShaymus It will effectively not exist as the first part of the `OR` condition will be true.

Comment: This works as far as delimiting the selected units.  However, whenever `(All Column Values)` is either manually selected or loaded as default. The analysis returns no data.

Comment: @iShaymus You state that the default value for `PROMPT_UNIT_NAME` is `'(All Column Values)'` and that is exactly what I am testing for in the alternate filter condition. You are going to need to debug the statement and work out where it is going wrong (it might be that it is returning extra whitespaces around the value or something else) but based on your question it should work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hcU550_k)

Comment: You are quite correct.  It looks like OBIEE is playing games with how it's sending through the unit presentation variable when it's in a default `AND SITE_LOCATION_NAME in ('Wellington')     AND (  '' = '(All Column Values)'        OR ',' || '' || ',' LIKE  '%,' || UNIT_LOCATION_NAME || ',%'        )`

Comment: Upon analysis of the physical SQL being executed by OBIEE it sends an empty string of `''` when `(All Column Values)` is selected even though OBIEE itself shows the presentation variable as having a value of `(All Column Values)`.  I got this working and using the following `AND (  CASE WHEN '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
       OR ',' || '@{PROMPT_UNIT_NAME}' || ',' LIKE  '%,' || UNIT_LOCATION_NAME || ',%'
       )`